# Hide ellipsis (…) button of expandable property like "…" button of font property in the property grid

Tags: c#, winforms, custom-controls, propertygrid, design-time

I've added a new property to my custom control as expandable property like font property in Property Grid. After using from my custom control in a Windows Forms Application project, I see an ellipsis (…) button like "…" button of font property in Property Grid. (For more information, please see the following picture.)

[image: One of my custom control properties]

Now, I want to hide the ellipsis (…) button for my new expandable property.

Expandable property codes are:

```
[DisplayName("Floors Information")]
[Description("Floors Informationnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn")]
[DefaultProperty("TitleText")]
[DesignerCategory("Component")]
public class FloorsInformation : DockContainerItem
{
    private SimilarFloorsInformation similarFloorsInformation = new SimilarFloorsInformation();

    public FloorsInformation()
    {

    }

    [Category("Data")]
    [DisplayName("Similar Floors Panel")]
    [Description("Similar Floors Panellllllllllllllllllll")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    [Editor(typeof(ItemsCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    //[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
    //[TypeConverter(typeof(SimilarFloorsInformationTypeConverter))]
    public SimilarFloorsInformation SimilarFloorsInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return similarFloorsInformation;
        }
    }
}

[DisplayName("Similar Floors Information")]
[Description("Similar Floors Informationnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn")]
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[DesignerCategory("Component")]
[TypeConverter(typeof(SimilarFloorsInformationTypeConverter))]
//[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class SimilarFloorsInformation : ExpandablePanel
{
    private Color canvasColor = SystemColors.Control;
    private eCollapseDirection collapseDirection = eCollapseDirection.LeftToRight;
    private eDotNetBarStyle colorSchemeStyle = eDotNetBarStyle.StyleManagerControlled;
    private DockStyle dock = DockStyle.Right;
    private eTitleButtonAlignment expandButtonAlignment = eTitleButtonAlignment.Left;
    private bool expanded = false;
    private bool markupUsesStyleAlignment = true;
    private Size size = new Size(30, 177);

    public SimilarFloorsInformation()
    {

    }
}

public class SimilarFloorsInformationTypeConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter//TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(SimilarFloorsInformation))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(String) && value is SimilarFloorsInformation)
        {
            SimilarFloorsInformation similarFloorsInformation = (SimilarFloorsInformation)value;
            return similarFloorsInformation.TitleText;
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            SimilarFloorsInformation similarFloorsInformation = new SimilarFloorsInformation();
            similarFloorsInformation.TitleText = (string)value;
            return similarFloorsInformation;
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem according to Nikolay Khil answer. Ellipsis (...) button is shown for following line of code (Attribute) that I've applied to the "**SimilarFloorsInfo**" property of my custom control:

```
[Editor(typeof(ItemsCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
```

So, this line of code must be deleted or commented. Now, Ellipsis (...) button not shown for my property in the property grid.

Answer (score 5):

You should implement your own class derived from [`UITypeEditor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.uitypeeditor.aspx) and override [`GetEditStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtsths3h.aspx) method as follows:

```
public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
{
    return UITypeEditorEditStyle.None;
}
```

Then use [`EditorAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorattribute.aspx):

```
[Editor(typeof(YourTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
```

### Update 1:

Well. I just realized you're already applying `EditorAttribute` on the property:

```
[Editor(typeof(ItemsCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public SimilarFloorsInformation SimilarFloorsInfo
{
    get
    {
        return similarFloorsInformation;
    }
}
```

So you should override `GetEditStyle` in `ItemsCollectionEditor`.

Comment: Tnx Nikolay Khil. I will check it.

Comment: Nikolay Khil, your answer didn't work for me. Ellipsis (…) button is still shown for my property in the property grid.

Comment: @MRS1367. I've updated my answer. Let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: Tnx Nikolay Khil. I will check it.

Comment: I found the reason of displaying the ellipsis (…) button according to your answer. Tnx Nikolay Khil.