# Exposing internal objects of a user control in the properties view of the designer?

Tags: vb.net, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer, design-time

I've already had success exposing a collection of items in the vb.net designer using DesignerSerializationVisibility(Content).  Now I have a new twist.  The items in my collection for a certain custom control are immutable--i.e. items can neither be added nor removed.  All I want is to expose the items of my collection in the properties panel of the designer so that a developer can tweak the individual properties of each item in the predefined collection of items.

When I tried DesignerSerializationVisibility(Content) it allows the developer to manage the items but rather than editing the existing items it attempts to re-add the items to the collection, which causes key collisions.

As a result I figured it might make sense to expose each item of the collection as its own property.  I used DesignerSerializationVisiblity(Visible) and (Content) and both just display the type name in the properties window but the object it exposes is not visible in a way that it can have its properties manipulated.

Am I missing something or can this not be done?  I read somewhere about using a TypeConverter.  Is this right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093473/group-properties-in-custom-control

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your Question correctly, you want to change a property to expandable property that has several sub-property.

If I understand properly, you must create a class that is derived from **ExpandableObjectConverter**. And use this class with **TypeConverterAttribute** for your property or that class that is related with your property.

For more information, please see my question that its link is offered in below:

[Hide ellipsis (…) button of expandable property like “…” button of font property in the property grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12826684/1625883)